# Changing the address of a local variable

Tags: c++, pointers, swap

I want to swap two local variables using the [xor algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm), however it will not allow me to change the address of the variables. If I create pointers to the variables, it will allow it, but is it possible to do this without using pointers?

I am trying to do this

```
Point a = Point();
Point b = Point(1,1);

&a ^= &b;
&b ^= &a;
&a ^= &b;
```

This is the closest I have been able to get to what I want to do

```
Point a = Point();
Point b = Point(1,1);

Point *a_ptr = &a;
Point *b_ptr = &b;

a_ptr = (Point *)(((unsigned long)a_ptr) ^ (unsigned long)b_ptr);
b_ptr = (Point *)(((unsigned long)a_ptr) ^ (unsigned long)b_ptr);
b_ptr = (Point *)(((unsigned long)a_ptr) ^ (unsigned long)b_ptr);

// The pointers are switched, but this will not work
&a = a_ptr;
```

Comment: Why do you want to swap in this fashion

Comment: @aaronman - No particular reason. Just wondering if it was possible.

Comment: You simply can't reassign the address of a variable. There's no reason I see to support that.

Comment: Forget about XOR swap, it forces the compiler to generate strictly sequential code. A smart compiler knows how to keep CPU pipelines busy and, even better, might simply note the variables are "swapped" and not generate any code at all. Prefer `std::swap` and turn on optimizations.

Comment: @Blastfurnace already recommended std::swap and not to say that xor is a good method but swapping values could be slower than ptr manipulation if the object is large

Comment: @aaronman: "pointer manipulation" is not a useful term, and leads to this kind of confusion. In C++11, we now have the clearer mechanism of moving.

Comment: @MSalters I mentioned moving read my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C language variables don't exist at runtime like variables in higher-level languages. Local variable "a" means, to the compiler, "the address of the stack frame - 2", or whatever it is. This reference exists only at compile time, and is fixed by the declaration. At runtime, the generated code simply fetches from the hard-coded address. So making the variable point to a different place with code is trying to change something that doesn't exist.

Comment: In modern compilers, `a` isn't even fixed like you describe here. It can vary within the function. E.g. before the swap ,it could be `a=register EAX, b=register EBX`. After the swap, it would be `a=register EBX, a=register EAX`. I.e. the swap did not move the values around at assembly level, and no instructions were needed. Just an update to the compilers' bookkeeping.

Comment: Exactly, and all that happens at compile time.

Comment: Just to clarify, the comment was about the "fixed by the declaration" part. The declaration has nothing to do with it anymore. Its allocation is now determined by assignment(s).

Answer (score 1):

The only way that it would be possible is if you actually did the xor swap on the values of the point. In your code it seems like you are trying to set the address of a value on the stack which you cannot do.

What I recommend is using `std::swap`.
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap.
To use this your object will gave to be moveContructible and moveAssignable.

So in short no, exactly what you want to do is not possible because you cannot assign to the address of a variable. But you can achieve a similar effect in multiple ways using the values of point, making pointers or `std::swap`