# Address of operator and L-values in c

Tags: c, pointers, memory-address

If I run the following code:

```
int main(){
    int x = 0;
    int* y = &x;
    &x = y;
}
```

I get the  error:

> lvalue required as left operand of assignment

I understand this means that when using the addressof operator, the pointer produced is not a valid lvalue, as is reflected in the c documentation.

My question simply is: why?

What is the reason that I cannot change the value of the pointer to my variable x? Is it to prevent the programmer from making mistakes, or does it fundamentally make no sense (in which case please explain why.)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the address of a local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17460360/changing-the-address-of-a-local-variable)

Comment: It makes as much sense as `x + 1 = 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
&x = y;
```

Sounds like you're trying to say "I want `x` to be stored in the address `y`".

1. When your declare a variable (`x`), its address (what you call "pointer value") is a constant value. It's NOT an "lvalue". ("l" for "left", a left part of an assignement operation, so something  assignable.)
2. Also you're not meant to decide yourself where the system sets the datas in memory.
3. Plus, you're not even sure the "y" address is an allocated place allowed to be written by your process.

Three reasons here to not let you do that. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here `&` operator gives you the address of the variable `x` and you are trying to assign something to that address, but that's not possible, it doesn't make sense.
If you want to change the value stored in `x`, just assign to it:

```
x = 5;
```

If you have a pointer (`int*`) `y` and you want to assign its value to `x`, use `*` operator to get the **value** y points to (stored in that address) and assign it to `x`:

```
x = *y;
```

If you want to assign the pointer `y` to `x`, it is not possible. Use another poiner for for that.

```
int *y1 = y;
```

Answer (score -1):

In your code

```
&x = y
```

This line shows an error as **&x is a constant pointer and hence cannot be changed after it has been initialized**

Comment: The issue has nothing to do with `const`-ness, but rather with the fact that it's not an lvalue. `&x` is also not a thing that has a concept of initialized-ness.